# How do I Avoid Those Raptors?

Tags: it-belongs-in-an-ancient-ruin

Towards the end of [It Belongs in an Ancient Ruin](http://itbelongsinanancientruin.com/), you start to encounter some kind of lizard things that like to jump out at you from behind some admittedly conspicuous shrubbery.  The problem is, knowing where the raptors[?] will come from doesn't really seem to be helping me avoid them very reliably.

[image: Oh no, not again.]

How do I know when they will strike?  What triggers the raptors' attack?  How can it be avoided?

Comment: What is it with you and raptors, man?

Comment: @Raven What's wrong with Raptors??

Comment: Absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raptors hide in bushes. Bushes usually come in pairs.

When you are close to the bush they are hiding in, raptors start jumping at you and then running fast and straight to the bush they were not hiding in in the first place. They will hide in this bush. The process might repeat.

You can notice a raptor:

- only **jumps** when it first jumps out of the bush it was hiding in,
- will then **run** to the next bush, without jumping (yet still deadly if touched), so that it can be avoided by a simple jump.

I have finished this game. If I can remember correctly, the trick is either:

- to anticipate and jump over him ; your jump should begin before the attack,
- to run back (to avoid the jump of the raptor) and back again (while the raptor is running straight) so that you jump above it,
- to be killed, to respawn, and finally to use the fact the raptor will be in the other bush, which may be easier to deal with.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think re-spawning sends the raptor back to the initial bush.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the developer who created the raptor AI in It Belongs in an Ancient Ruin. If you're a real boss, you can walk underneath them when they jump out to attack you.

Actually, we figured out that at the particular bush in your screenshot, you can walk from the coat hanger to the other side of the bush in complete safety. Raptors tend to attack you either the instant they see you from their bushes, or a second or so afterwards.

You can tell if a raptor is hiding in a bush if the bush rustles every few seconds.

Thank's for playing! We love to hear stories from people who have played IBAR and we hope you beat the game so you could find out the Curator's evil secret...

Answer (score 0):

According to the trailer, these are Velociraptors. They seem to attack when you get too close to the bush.
The way that I would suggest for avoiding them is either jump/swing over the bushes or avoid them (when possible :)

Comment: It's often impossible to avoid them, and since the raptors seem to spring out quasi-randomly, just 'jumping over the bush' doesn't work particularly well.